# Get All Objects From Glade File

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade, pygobject

I know it's possible to import specific objects from a glade file using:

```
builder.add_objects_from_file("example.glade", ("button1", "button2"))
```

But as you can see, I have to pass a list of the objects I want to import.

Is there a way to import everything in the .glade file? All the objects without having to specify their names here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `gtk_builder_add_objects_from_file`, you are merging specific objects to an existing GtkBuilder instance which will then instantiate those same objects. Using this function/method is only useful if you need a specific set of objects from a UI definition file.

The normal use of `GtkBuilder`, would be to load it entirely and then retrieve the object you want to deal with `gtk_builder_get_object`. But if your goal is to retrieve all the objects, then use `gtk_builder_get_objects` which will return a `GSList`. Using this function/method assumes that you already loaded a UI definition file from a file or from another possible source.

As [documented](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-get-objects):

> `GSList *gtk_builder_get_objects (GtkBuilder *builder);`
>
> Gets all objects that have been constructed by builder . Note that
>   this function does not increment the reference counts of the returned
>   objects.
>
> **Returns**
>
> a newly-allocated GSList containing all the objects constructed by the
>   GtkBuilder instance. It should be freed by g_slist_free().

Comment: I am aware of this approach but for some reason it's not working with me. I wrote: builder = Gtk.Builder();builder.add_from_file("ui/myui.glade");builder.get_objects(). But when I try to use a method for an object I made in the glade file (like if I created a window, and named it window1), Python will tell me: NameError: name 'window1' is not defined

Comment: @Madno Is there a reason to get all objects at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using something like "window = gtk_builder_get_object("window1")" for each object and thing I have in the glade file, I want to make it in few lines. Which is why I am asking about a way to import all the objects, then, I can use something like window1.set_title("title") directly.

Comment: @Madno Hmmm it doesnt work that way. When you create a UI via glade, there will be a lot of widgets that you don't need to use programmatically, so getting a pointer to them its completely redundant and irrelevant. Once you have your GtkBuilder filled with data from a file, it will instantiate all the widgets (it's like a "automatic" factory pattern). Then you need to retrieve the widgets you want to use, when you need them. For that you use the normal methodology, button = builder.get_object ("button1") and then button.set_label(....

Comment: @Madno if you use get_objects method you will then have a linked list of object/widgets on which you must iterate to get the exact object you want and even then you need a "pointer" to the widget/object if you want to reuse it. So, do as normal... keep the builder as a property on your python class and you will be able to retrieve the widgets/objects when and where you need them inside that same python class/object scope. Did you understand or i've made you more confused?

Comment: Yea I understood :) Thank you.

Comment: Nice :) Feel free to ask more questions if you need. Good luck with Gtk ;)